# What is the new getMyLocation function instead of the deprecated one? (Android Java)

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google maps activity and i want to get the location of the user,
but the function i want to use: `getMyLocation()`  is deprecated.

Here is my piece of code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    // This function is deprecated
    // What is the new function?
    mMap.getMyLocation();

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation()):

> use com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead. FusedLocationProviderApi provides improved location finding and power usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot. See the MyLocationDemoActivity in the sample applications folder for example example code, or [the Location Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location).

IOW, there is no replacement method. Instead, you use other APIs for finding the user's location.

Comment: @Stackingcoder: You can use Play Services' fused location API (the one referenced in the answer) or use [the one native to Android itself](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).

Comment: FusedLocationApi is prone to the wifi/cell location bug. This is when cell tower has wrong location info and when no gps, this provider may report location many kilometers away from the real location. But GoogleMap seems to have some workaround for this bug. So there is a good reason to use getMyLocation() function. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184005

Google Maps is closed source, though it would be great if someone would enlighten us as to how Google Maps actually deal with this problem.